# Как запустить анимацию вращения через равные промежутки?

Tags: css, svg, анимация, css-animation, svg-animation

1. Как запустить анимацию вращения
2. Чтобы сразу работало левый верхний угол
3. Затем через 2 секунды правый верхний угол
4. Затем через 2 секунды левый нижний угол
5. Затем через 2 секунды правый нижний угол

```css
circle{
  stroke-dasharray: 3 2;
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 3;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  animation: anima 2s linear forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes anima{
  100%{
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect x="100" y="80" width="150" height="100" fill="" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>  
  <circle r="10" cx="105" cy="80" fill="red" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
  <circle r="10" cx="105" cy="140" fill="red" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
  <circle r="10" cx="250" cy="80" fill="red" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
  <circle r="10" cx="250" cy="140" fill="red" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
circle:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

circle:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

circle:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Варианты анимации SVG

Ответ на вопрос ТС Запуск анимации реализуется аналогично анимации CSS, но выставляется не время задержки, а запуск по времени: 0s ;2s; 4s; 6s

Обычно в SVG анимациях используется комплексный подход:

1. расчет таймингов запуска, задержки, как в CSS
2. управление анимациями с помощью логических цепочек, прописанных в атрибуте `begin`

Этот способ будет показан на примерах ниже.

А сейчас повторение анимации CSS, - последовательный запуск вращения колес:

```html
<svg width="200" height="150" viewBox="75 55 200 150" style="border:1px solid gray">
  
  <rect x="100" y="80" width="150" height="100" /> 
<g stroke="red" stroke-width="15" fill="none" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="3 2"  >  
  <circle  r="16" cx="100" cy="80" >
  <!-- Верхнее левое колесо    -->
   <animate id="TL"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="0s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
  </circle > 
    <!-- Верхнее правое колесо -->
  <circle  r="16" cx="250" cy="80"  >
     <animate id="TR"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="2s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
  </circle> 
   <!-- Нижнее левое колесо    -->  
  <circle  r="16" cx="100" cy="180">
     <animate id="BL"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="4s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
  </circle> 
     <!-- Нижнее правое колесо    --> 
  <circle  r="16" cx="250" cy="180" >
    <animate id="BR"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="6s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle> 
</g> 
</svg>
```

**Запуск анимации колес попарно**

1. Верхние колеса крутятся 2s `dur="2s"`
2. Верхняя пара колес останавливается - по окончанию `2s`
3. Запуск вращения нижней пары колес
   И здесь уже можно включать логические цепочки: `begin="TR.end"` запуск, когда заканчивается анимация вращения правого верхнего колеса, где TR (Top Right) id анимации
4. Зацикливание анимации
   Вращение нижней пары останавливается, запускается анимация верхней пары колёс

`begin="0s;BR.end"`, где `0s` первый запуск анимации ; `BR.end"` повторный запуск анимации верхних колес, когда закончилась анимация вращения нижних колёс

```html
<svg width="200" height="150" viewBox="75 55 200 150" style="border:1px solid gray">
  
  <rect x="100" y="80" width="150" height="100" fill="skyblue" /> 
<g stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="15" fill="none" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="23 2.132"  >  
  <circle  r="16" cx="100" cy="80" >
      <!-- Верхнее левое колесо -->
 <animate id="TL"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="0s;BR.end" dur="2s" repeatCount="1"/> 
  </circle > 
  <circle  r="16" cx="250" cy="80"  >
    <!-- Верхнее правое колесо   -->
  <animate id="TR"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="0s;BR.end" dur="2s" repeatCount="1"/> 
  </circle>  
  <circle  r="16" cx="100" cy="180">
      <!-- Нижнее левое колесо -->
  <animate id="BL"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="TR.end" dur="2s" repeatCount="1"/> 
  </circle>
  <circle  r="16" cx="250" cy="180" >
      <!-- Нижнее правое колесо -->
 <animate id="BR"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="TR.end" dur="2s" repeatCount="1"/>
  </circle> 
</g> 
</svg>
```

### Более сложный пример комплексной анимации

**Сценарий:**

1. Вращение верхней пары колес
2. Вращение нижней пары колес по часовой стрелке
3. Одновременно с вращением начинается движение всего объекта вправо
4. По окончанию движения `1s` пауза
5. Вращение нижней пары колес против часовой стрелки
6. Движения объекта назад
7. Зацикливание, всё начинается снова

```html
<svg width="600" height="150" viewBox="75 55 600 150" style="border:1px solid gray">
 <g id="obj"> 
   <rect x="100" y="80" width="150" height="100" fill="skyblue" /> 
 <g stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="15" fill="none" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="31 2.5"  >  
   <circle  r="16" cx="100" cy="80" >
  <!-- Вращение верхнего левого колёса -->
  <animate id="TL"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="0s;back.end" dur="2s" repeatCount="1"/> 
   </circle > 
    
   <circle  r="16" cx="250" cy="80"  >
     <!-- Вращение верхнего правого колёса -->
   <animate id="TR"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="0s;back.end" dur="2s" repeatCount="1"/> 
   </circle>  
   <circle  r="16" cx="100" cy="180">
    <!-- Вращение нижнего левого колёса вправо -->
   <animate id="BL"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="TR.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="1"/> 
        
    <!-- Вращение нижнего левого колёса влево -->
   <animate id="BL"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="-100;0" begin="back.begin" dur="4s" repeatCount="1"/> 
   </circle>
   
      <!-- Вращение нижнего правого колёса вправо -->
   <circle  r="16" cx="250" cy="180" >
  <animate id="BR"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="TR.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="1"/>
      
      <!-- Вращение нижнего правого колёса влево -->
    <animate id="BR"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="-100;0" begin="back.begin" dur="4s" repeatCount="1"/>
   </circle> 
 </g> 
</g>
 <animateTransform id="forward" xlink:href="#obj" attributeName="transform" type="translate" dur="4s" begin="TR.end"  values="0 0;400 0" fill="freeze" /> 
   <animateTransform id="back" xlink:href="#obj" attributeName="transform" type="translate" dur="4s" begin="forward.end+1s"  values="400 0;0 0" fill="freeze" /> 
</svg>
```

Comment: столько svg тегов которые я еще не знаю :((

Comment: @Leks Изучай, задавай вопросы, пусть примеры будут нерабочие, в боевой обстановке вопрос-ответ изучение пойдет быстрее. Я вот даже не знаю, возможно ли повторить данную анимацию на CSS и насколько она будет объёмна и трудоёмка по расчету таймингов..

Comment: хорошо (какой-то текст)

Comment: тег g как я понял просто объединяет содержимое ?

Comment: отошел скоро буду но это не точно :((

Comment: @Leks Да, `<g id="obj">` объединяет прямоугольник и круги в одну группу, чтобы двигать её   вперед-назад  `<animateTransform id="forward" xlink:href="#obj"`

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex я не знаток CSS-animation очень было бы интересно посмотреть решение на CSS вот этой анимации SVG, что выше

Comment: Я тоже не знаток, но это выглядело бы как-то [так](https://jsfiddle.net/86kxpfv0/). Можно ещё со значением `reverse` как-нибудь придумать в целях сокращения кода, но мне сегодня уже лень этим заниматься )

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex благодарю, интересно. А потом сможете, если будет желание с pure CSS без JS попробовать сделать?

Comment: Это можно сделать без js? Максимум, что могу https://jsfiddle.net/3w27ayn4/

Comment: Хотя.... Сейчас попробую

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex мне действительно очень интересно посмотреть, как в CSS можно сделать без мучительного высчитывания таймингов. В SVG вот видишь я организовал логические цепочки и запускай анимации. **Хочешь я отдельный вопрос оформлю, там  опубликуешь свои ответы, чтобы не пропал твой труд**

Comment: Не не нужно. Да можно на css сделать, попозже скину.

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex Класс! Успел посмотреть код. я всё же оформлю вопрос :) На такие простые вопросы отвечаешь, и на новый, будущий вопрос ответь пожалуйста. Уверен, твой ответ будет востребован и хорошо встречен

Comment: Сделал таки https://jsfiddle.net/yxfrq5o7/, пробовал по разному, но с этим дилэем в начале вижу только такой выход.

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex Просто здорово!!! Публикуй ответ -https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1060900/28748