# Как оптимально реализовать последовательно-параллельную анимацию CSS

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Этот вопрос инициирован  [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1060796/28748) по реализации последовательно-параллельной анимации в SVG:

**Сценарий анимации:**

1. Вращение верхней пары колес
2. Вращение нижней пары колес по часовой стрелке
3. Одновременно с вращением начинается движение всего объекта вправо
4. По окончанию движения `1s` пауза
5. Вращение нижней пары колес против часовой стрелки
6. Движения объекта назад
7. Зацикливание, всё начинается снова

```html
<svg width="600" height="150" viewBox="75 55 600 150" style="border:1px solid gray">
 <g id="obj"> 
   <rect x="100" y="80" width="150" height="100" fill="skyblue" /> 
 <g stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="15" fill="none" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="31 2.5"  >  
   <circle  r="16" cx="100" cy="80" >
  <!-- Вращение верхнего левого колёса -->
  <animate id="TL"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="0s;back.end" dur="2s" repeatCount="1"/> 
   </circle > 
    
   <circle  r="16" cx="250" cy="80"  >
     <!-- Вращение верхнего правого колёса -->
   <animate id="TR"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="0s;back.end" dur="2s" repeatCount="1"/> 
   </circle>  
   <circle  r="16" cx="100" cy="180">
    <!-- Вращение нижнего левого колёса вправо -->
   <animate id="BL"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="TR.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="1"/> 
        
    <!-- Вращение нижнего левого колёса влево -->
   <animate id="BL"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="-100;0" begin="back.begin" dur="4s" repeatCount="1"/> 
   </circle>
   
      <!-- Вращение нижнего правого колёса вправо -->
   <circle  r="16" cx="250" cy="180" >
  <animate id="BR"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100" begin="TR.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="1"/>
      
      <!-- Вращение нижнего правого колёса влево -->
    <animate id="BR"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="-100;0" begin="back.begin" dur="4s" repeatCount="1"/>
   </circle> 
 </g> 
</g>
 <animateTransform id="forward" xlink:href="#obj" attributeName="transform" type="translate" dur="4s" begin="TR.end"  values="0 0;400 0" fill="freeze" /> 
   <animateTransform id="back" xlink:href="#obj" attributeName="transform" type="translate" dur="4s" begin="forward.end+1s"  values="400 0;0 0" fill="freeze" /> 
</svg>
```

Данный сценарий легко реализуется в SVG выстраиванием логических цепочек в атрибуте  `begin="0s;back.end"`. Не надо мучиться с расчётом времени, как в анимациях CSS.

И тем не менее, нужно аналогичное решение на CSS, так как не все браузеры воспринимают SMIL SVG, в первую очередь - `IE` и `Edge`.
Решение желательно с помощью pure CSS, в крайнем случае допустимо немного JS кода.

Answer (score 11):

```css
circle {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

circle:nth-of-type(1),
circle:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation: top-wheel-animation 10s infinite;
}


circle:nth-of-type(3),
circle:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation: bottom-wheel-animation 10s infinite;
}


rect {
  animation: rectangle-animation 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes top-wheel-animation {
  /* верхние колёса начинают вращаться */
  20% { /* верхние колёса заканчивают вращение  */
    transform: translateX(0) rotate(360deg);
  }
  
  /* верхние колёса движутся вправо */
  55%, 65% { /* достигают значения ниже и одну секунду соят на месте */
    transform: translateX(400px) rotate(360deg);
  }
  
  /* верхние колёса движутся влево */
  to { /* верхние колёса возвращаются в исходную точку */
    transform: translateX(0) rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rectangle-animation {
  /* имитация animation-delay */
  20% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  
  /* Прямоугольник движется вправо */
  55%, 65% { /* достигает значения 400px и стоит месте */
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
  /* Прямоугольник возвращается в исходное положениие */
}

@keyframes bottom-wheel-animation {
  /* имитация свойства animation-delay */
  20% {
    transform: translateX(0) rotate(0);
  }
  
  /* нижние колёса движутся вправо и вращаются */
  55%, 65% { /* достигают знаяения ниже и стоят месте */
    transform: translateX(400px) rotate(360deg);
  }
   /* нижние колёса возвращаются в исходное положениие */
}
```

```html
<svg width="600" height="150" viewBox="75 55 600 150" style="border:1px solid gray">
  
  <rect x="100" y="80" width="150" height="100" fill="skyblue" /> 
  <g stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="15" fill="none" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="23 2.132"  >  
    <circle r="16" cx="100" cy="80" ></circle > 
    <circle r="16" cx="250" cy="80"  ></circle>  
    <circle r="16" cx="100" cy="180"></circle>
    <circle r="16" cx="250" cy="180" ></circle> 
  </g> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Можно немного поясняющих комментарий в код? Не все читают код с листа. Пожалуйста, хоть самый минимум, чтобы оценить красоту решения

Comment: про красоту не уверен, но что есть, то есть )

Comment: @Alexandr_TT пойдут такие комментарии? Просто `css` сам себя документирует...

Comment: @ hu-fo-of-ex точнее наверное колеса вращаются по часовой, против часовой стрелки. Неточность - стоит 1 мин заменить на 1 сек. **Что-то** движется, - лучше заменить на конкретику